# Combine multiple "equals ... or"

Tags: javascript

```
  var group = 4;
  var level = [1,2];
  var options = 'ng;nk';

  var arrayWithCorrectGroup = shuffledArray.filter(innerArray => innerArray[0] === group);
  var arrayWithCorrectLevels = arrayWithCorrectGroup.filter(x => x[1] === level[0] || x[1] === level[1] );
  var arrayWithCorrectValues = arrayWithCorrectLevels.filter(x => x[3].includes(...options.split(';')));
```

When using `.includes` as seen in `arrayWithCorrectValues`, you can use the three dots to loop through all options in the array. I want to know if there is a similar way for the equals or in the `arrayWithCorrectLevels`. It's possible to have an array with 10 levels. I don't want to write `x[1] === level[n]` ten times.

Comment: `level.includes(x[1])`?

Comment: `When using .includes as seen in arrayWithCorrectValues, you can use the three dots to loop through all options in the array` thios is not true. And yes you can do `level.includes(x[1])`

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You code is currently not standalone.

Comment: And yes, @Vulwsztyn is correct: the signature of `includes` is `<T>(searchElement: T, fromIndex?: number | undefined): boolean` for arrays and `(searchString: string, position?: number | undefined): boolean` for strings. Spreading will not work: for numbers it will be pretty unpredictable, as the second number will set the start index, and for strings only the first string will be searched for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to check if x[1] is equal to any element of the level array.

Example one:

```
level.includes(x[1]);
```

Example two:

```
level.some(item => item === x[1]);
```